# How to save data changes in MYSQL column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-workbench, alter-table

I have received a database, where I had to change the date format on one of the tables into msql date format. I was wondering how to save these changes on MySQL, once I conduct the command:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(last_post_date) 
FROM it_forum;
```

The column that I want to change to is below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would typically create a new column, fill it from the old column and then drop the old column:

```
-- rename the "old" column
alter table mytable rename column last_post_date to last_post_date_old; 

-- create the "new" column
alter table mytable add last_post_date datetime;

-- feed the "new" column
update mytable set last_post_date = from_unixtime(last_post_date_old);

-- drop the "old" column
alter table mytable drop column last_post_date_old;
```

You need downtime on the table to run this safely.

Note: the `rename` syntax is available in MySQL 8.0 only. In earlier versions, you need to use the more cumbersome `change` syntax, which requires redeclaring the datatype (the following assumes `int`):

```
alter table mytable change last_post_date last_post_date_old int;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e57514150d89a959038d52d05c143fe)**

Before:

```
| last_post_date |
| -------------: |
|     1591132456 |
```

After:

```
| last_post_date      |
| :------------------ |
| 2020-06-02 22:14:16 |
```